# GeoServer Deployment of custom WPS

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wps, deployment

I'm currently facing challenges deploying a custom Web Processing Service (WPS) process in GeoServer 2.23.0, Geotool 29.0 and I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue. Following the steps outlined in the GeoServer Documentation, specifically the tutorial named gs:helloWPS ([Tutorial Link](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implementing.html)), I successfully created a JAR file, hello_wps-2.8-SNAPSHOT.jar, and placed it in GeoServer's `WEB/INF` directory.

Despite these efforts, the deployed WPS process is not visible in either the GeoServer WPS Request Builder or the logs. I've thoroughly reviewed the documentation and forum discussions, but unfortunately, I haven't found any relevant information pertaining to GeoServer 2.23.0.

Do you have any experience or insights into deploying custom WPS processes in GeoServer 2.23.0 that could help me?

The details of my problem involve the lack of visibility for the deployed process in both the WPS Request Builder and the logs.

my POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd ">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>hello_wps</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <version>2.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>hello_wps</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <gt.version>29.0</gt.version> <!-- GeoTools version -->
    <gs.version>2.23.0</gs.version> <!-- GeoServer version -->
</properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-process</artifactId>
        <version>${gt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geoserver.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs-wps-core</artifactId>
        <version>${gs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs-main</artifactId>
        <version>${gs.version}</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add your other dependencies here -->
</dependencies>


   <build>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
           <source>1.8</source>
           <target>1.8</target>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>boundless</id>
            <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>https://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: What do the logs say when starting up the WPS? if there is really no mention of it at all then you have probably not created or made a mistake in your `org.geotools.process.ProcessFactory` file. Do your unit tests cover creating and running the process and do they pass?

Comment: Your jar(s) should go in `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: Hello Ian, i didnt found any org.geotools.process.ProcessFactory at first but i create one. and  icant still found it in GeoServer and no mention at all in Logs for this WPS.

Comment: Do you have any tipps how should the org.geotools.process.ProcessFactory looks like. I create one via ChatGPT